# Why does my little Flask app with keras and tensorflow backend crash on subsequent image uploads?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, flask, keras

for an assignment, we did image classifcation with Keras and TF that image classifies dogs vs cats. I wrote a simple Flask app that allows for a demo of uploading a pic and display whether the uploaded image scores dog or cat.

I can run a single upload and that displays nicely, but if I upload another image, I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(3, 3, 3, 32), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

with the line:

```
  model = load_model('/Volumes/T5_500G/Capstone/v2/flask/models/model_weights.h5')
```

highlighted in flask debug page

I'm new to this so I'm confused as to how to fix this. Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/upload_image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_image():


    prediction_results = {}
    animals = ['% Cat Score', '% Dog Score']
    animals_scores = []
    imageUrl = ""

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if request.files:
            import keras
            from keras.models import load_model
            from keras import backend as K
            import numpy as np
            model = load_model('/Volumes/T5_500G/Capstone/v2/flask/models/model_weights.h5')
            print(request.files)
            print(request.files['image'].filename)
            imageUrl = "/static/uploads/"+request.files['image'].filename
            image2 = app.config['IMAGE_UPLOADS']+"/"+request.files['image'].filename
            request.files['image'].save(image2)
            img_path = image2
            img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224,224))
            img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
            expanded_img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
            preprocessed_img = expanded_img_array / 255. # Preprocess the image
            prediction = model.predict(preprocessed_img)
            pred_list = prediction.tolist()
            animals_scores.append(pred_list[0][0])
            animals_scores.append(pred_list[0][1])
            print(prediction_results)


            imageUrl = "/static/uploads/"+request.files['image'].filename
    return render_template('/upload_image.html',imageUrl=imageUrl, animals=animals, animals_scores=animals_scores)
```

The upload paths are paths on my laptop. I'm hoping to fix this an push to heroku or related.

I've read some posts about clearing the keras session. Is this the issue?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Just a comment: you're performing multiple imports and loading the model with each request, causing unnecessary disk reads will slow down your analysis. You can initialize a variable at Flask app level instead of your current method.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code a bit according to my comment, it should be working now.

````
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

model = load_model('/Volumes/T5_500G/Capstone/v2/flask/models/model_weights.h5')

@app.route('/upload_image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_image():
    prediction_results = {}
    animals = ['% Cat Score', '% Dog Score']
    animals_scores = []
    imageUrl = ""

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if request.files:

            print(request.files)
            print(request.files['image'].filename)
            imageUrl = "/static/uploads/"+request.files['image'].filename
            image2 = app.config['IMAGE_UPLOADS']+"/"+request.files['image'].filename
            request.files['image'].save(image2)
            img_path = image2
            img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224,224))
            img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
            expanded_img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
            preprocessed_img = expanded_img_array / 255. # Preprocess the image
            prediction = model.predict(preprocessed_img)
            pred_list = prediction.tolist()
            animals_scores.append(pred_list[0][0])
            animals_scores.append(pred_list[0][1])
            print(prediction_results)


            imageUrl = "/static/uploads/"+request.files['image'].filename
    return render_template('/upload_image.html',imageUrl=imageUrl, animals=animals, animals_scores=animals_scores)```
````

Comment: Thanks Kaipit. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I added 
```K.clear_session()```
towards the bottom and that cleared up the crashing. I added your code changes, but not it's crashing at
 ```prediction = model.predict(preprocessed_img)```

Comment: I can push my code to gitlab if you're interested running it.